Argparse - Check if positional argument is entered
with argparse, is it possible to check whether the first positional argument has been entered:
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("object_type", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--pass1", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--pass2", type=str)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(args)

when calling: myscript.py --pass1=foo, I get the error:
error: the following arguments are required: object_type
what makes sense, but there don't seem to be a way to catch the error beforehand.
Something like:
if args.object_type is None:
    raise argparse.ArgumentError(message="object_type must be defined!")

tried also with try/except with no luck.
possible or not ?

Yeah, when you fail to give it the required arguments it returns on a sys.exit(2) from  argparse itself and there's no way to catch that... probably.

Ok, I found a duplicate question
The way to bypass the required positional is to add the kwarg nargs='?' to the positional add_argument.  Then, you'll need to check using some other means

Does this answer your question? Argparse optional positional arguments?

actually not, since my positional argument is not optional. Unless positional forcibly means mandatory

The docs talk about changing the parser.error and parser.exit methods to capture an error., keeping it from exiting.  There is also an exit_on_error parameter, but that may not work with this error, since it isn't redirecting a ArgumentError incident.

One of the last steps in parsing is to check if any required arguments have not been seen.  If so, it raises an error, and (normally) exits with a message like this.  While it is possible to redirect the exit, normal practice is to change parser setup so such an argument isn't required, and letting the user's code deal with a default (like None).
